# Selenium "waiting for fonts.googleapis.com" pretty long time

Tags: firefox, selenium, fonts, webfonts

We're using Selenium to test a web app that uses fonts.googleapis.com. Our problem is that at the first Selenium test the test seems to wait a pretty long lime (around 10 s) with text "Waiting for fonts.googleapis.com" at Firefox left bottom corner.

Full page refresh with Firefox is clearly faster, around 2-3 secs and the request doesn't seem to take that long.

Some ideas?

Comment: Much more details needed. What version of Selenium? What version of Firefox? Clear your Firefox cache (fully), and do the same - does the page take the same time? Is it the same in other browsers? What about if you try this on a different machine? Is this testing against a live site? If so, have your users ever encountered that problem? Have you tried disabling your 'extra' fonts (served by Google) and see if the page loads faster or does it just slow down and wait for a while at a different place?